# Building regular expression for Python

Tags: python, regex

```
\b(?:AN|AcntNumber) : (\w+)
```

the above regex prints the `'AcntNumber'` as well

```
AcntNumber : c422731c7c2a4f9cbe98fbfbf410265f
```

but I want only to print `c422731c7c2a4f9cbe98fbfbf410265f`. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: There is already a capturing group for the hex value. What Python code are you using here? You can just use `.group(1)` on the match object.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string from `:` and you have your Account Number.

```
>>> string = "AcntNumber : c422731c7c2a4f9cbe98fbfbf410265f"
>>> frags = string.split(':')
>>> number = frags[1].strip()
>>> number
'c422731c7c2a4f9cbe98fbfbf410265f'
```

Or:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "AcntNumber : c422731c7c2a4f9cbe98fbfbf410265f"
>>> e = "\b?:AN|AcntNumber : (\w+)"
>>> ext = re.findall(e, string)
>>> ext[0]
'c422731c7c2a4f9cbe98fbfbf410265f'
>>>
```

Comment: Why the `replace()` when you can have `strip()`? Or just `string.partition(' : ')[-1]`.

Comment: Didn't think of it, Sorry!

Comment: And don't use `re.findall()` unless you are expecting the possibility of multiple matches.

Comment: And why `re.split()` when `string.split(':')` would do the exact same thing without importing?